# For an iPhone map application, how do I create the graphs?

Tags: ios, data-structures, graph, dictionary

I want to make an application that is basically Google Maps for indoor places such as malls or airports. I know I have to create a graph from the floorplan and use a shortest-path-finding-algorithm to plot the shortest route from one location to another. 
How do I represent a mall or airport as a graph? Do I make each store or gate or something as a node and the walkways as edges? Or do I have to be much more specific, such as making a node every 5-10 feet? How specific do I need to be and what should I make the nodes and edges?

Comment: How do you display your map? PDF, SVG, image or draw it by yourself programmatically? And how do you apply your graph to map, I mean how do you determine vertexes and edges on map?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest perceiving the floor plan as a grid, where each cell represents *x* square meters. Place a node on each cell that lies within an accessibly area. The edges are between each neigbouring cell and all have a cost of *x*.

The advantage of this approach is that you can efficently lay this out in memory (you can put this in a matrix, rather than having to use adiecency lists or such). For pathfinding you can use a simple A* implementation that uses the Euclidian distance between two points as a heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different problems you want to solve here. First, there is the structural relation between two places, and second there is the geometrical one. Shortest path relies partly on the geometry, and partly on the structure. Eg. a pathway need not be the straight line. For the structure, you could represent the mall stores and gates as nodes, and the pathway as edges. Put the actual distance between nodes as the "weight" of the edge and use [Dijstra's algorihtm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path.

If you just need to present the results textually like "Go to A, then go to B", or on a metro (underground) style topological map, this is fine. But if you want to show the results on a geometrically accurate representation of the floor, you need to make the connection between the structure and the geometry stronger. I would suggest that you augment the structure described above with addition nodes everywhere the path takes a turn, and marking to nodes with x,y-coordinates as well as a bool for whether it is an intermediate node or not. Make only the true nodes selectable as source and destination, but use the whole graph for Dijkstra. When drawing the results on screen, iterate over the nodes in the shortest path and use their coordinates to draw a piecewise straight line from source to destination.

Comment: You can even use these augmented nodes in the textual results like "Go to A, continue for x meters, turn left and go ahead y meters to B".